# CSS - How to make in our border solid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

In HTML and CSS I have made an input widget. I have set its border and surrounding colours to green. However the border of the input is not 100%, there are still some hints of black in it, please can someone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it? Also, the text itself in the input is not green which property in CSS can resolve this?

An image is attached[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `border-style:solid` for that element in css

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `CSS`:

````
input{
  border : 1px solid green;
  outline = none;
}```
````